# How to prevent loading child view before parse will complete in objective c

Tags: parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

Would you be so kind to explain me, how i can prevent child view not to load before parse will complete.
Below I'll describe mine specific situation.
I have root view controller which begin parse query

```
if ( !_languageList )
    {
        [Language getAllObjectsWithBlockCompletion:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

            if ( error )
            {
                NSString *message = error.localizedDescription;
                if ( !message )
                {
                    message = NSLocalizedString(@"Unable to get language list", nil);
                }

                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                                            message:message
                                           delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil)
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            }
            else
            {
                _languageList = objects;
                _languageListViewController.languageList = objects;
            }

        }];
    }
```

After it finished, result are recorded in child view controllers property.
But when my app starts, another view loaded first like headband. There is stopbutton, if user press it quickly, next child view is loaded. Sometimes it can be loaded before it recive data from parse.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([InternetValidator isInternetEnable] == NO)
    {
      //  UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

      //  [message show];

        UIImageView *sprachoverlayy =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,140,320,190)];
        sprachoverlayy.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"nowifi.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:sprachoverlayy];
    }
    else
    {


        _splashViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[SplashViewController description]];
        [self addChildViewController:_splashViewController];

        _languageListViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[LanguageListViewController description]];
        [_languageListViewController setSelectionBlock:^(LanguageListViewController *sender, Language *language){

            [sender prepareForTransition:^{

                ScanViewController *controller = [sender.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[ScanViewController description]];
                controller.language = language;

                NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sender, controller, nil];
                [sender.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

            }];

        }];
        [_languageListViewController shouldScrollToLanguageWithCode:[_userDefaults objectForKey:UD_LANGUAGE_CODE] animated:NO];
        _languageNavigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_languageListViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:_languageNavigationController];

        _currentChildController = _splashViewController;
        [self.view addSubview:_currentChildController.view];
        [self _setupChildViewConstraints];

        _languageNavigationController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        [_splashViewController performPresentationAnimationWithBlockCompletion:^{
            if([_languageListViewController.languageList count]==0){
                NSLog(@"No info");
            }
            [self _clearChildViewConstraints];
            [self transitionFromViewController:_currentChildController
                              toViewController:_languageNavigationController
                                      duration:0.5
                                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                    animations:^{

                                        _languageNavigationController.view.alpha = 1.0f;

                                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                        _splashViewController = nil;
                                        _currentChildController = _languageNavigationController;
                                        [self _setupChildViewConstraints];

                                    }];


        }];

    }
    }

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if([InternetValidator isInternetEnable] == NO)
    {
        //   UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        //   [message show];
    }
    else
    {
        [self loadLangugeList];
    }

}
```